# Conditional appearance of gridview rows and columns in aspx devexpress

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview, appearance

I have a web project with devexpress component ASPxGridView. So I want to know is any apportunity to change rows appearences, and also to make conditional appearance providing some rules. I know how it works in windows application and want the same in aspx net.

Comment: And appearance changes like upon mouse hover row colour change or what? explain appearance changes you want.

Comment: no mouse events I don't nedd. For example I want to color those rows, where COUNT>10 ar something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For row appearance changes handle [ASPxGridView.HtmlRowPrepared](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_HtmlRowPreparedtopic) event.
For cell appearance changes handle [ASPxGridView.HtmlDataCellPrepared](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_HtmlDataCellPreparedtopic) event.

Answer (score 1):

Citing the example you gave you must make use of [GridView Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx). Like DataBount event is fired upon binding your data so you can change appearance like this:

```
protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowindex = e.Row.RowIndex;
        if (/* Your Condition */)
        {            
            GridView1.Rows[rowindex].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

in your aspx however you have to do something like this:

```
OnRowDataBound="GridView1_DataBound"
```

Similarly you can change appearance in other events like OnRowCreated which is fired at the time of Row Creation as name suggests.